# Requests Library producing Error Code 444 with Amazon EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, python-requests, http-status-codes

I'm making a bunch of webcalls to scrape for data utilizing Joblib and Requests which work fine on my own personal computer but when I moved the code to Amazon EC2 t3a.micro service, I run into a request error 444. requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 444 Client Error: Unknown for url. I believe this is because I am making too many requests in a limited time frame but was not sure how to exactly fix this problem or what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this httpstatus page](https://httpstatuses.com/444) the error comes from:

> A non-standard status code used to instruct nginx to close the
> connection without sending a response to the client, most commonly
> used to deny malicious or malformed requests.

So if you are 100% sure you use the same payload on EC2 and it is also correct, then it could indeed be the amount for requests. The way you limit the amount of requests is usually dependent on the code you wrote. I have seen people use the `sleep(5)` code to avoid flooding the server with requests. Not sure if it would work in your specific case though.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but there are a lot of requests that it has to run through and putting the delays would just increase the runtime by an extra day or two which is too long. Do you have any recommendations on using a different ec2 instance or alternative?

Comment: Generally the client is not the one with problems when it comes to 4xx pages. The server will be unable to handle requests and starts throwing timeouts when it can't keep up. If the runtime is increased too much then perhaps your scraper is inefficient or the server is never meant to be scraped (as is often the case). Does the site not have some form of API for you to connect to? As far as EC2 alternatives go, try researching into AWS Lambda, which allows you to run python code without worrying about infrastructure. Not quite sure what it does in terms of pricing compared to what you have now.

Comment: I don't think it is the API that I am connecting to because it works fine on my own private network. I believe it is because EC2 Instance is throttling my request but I am not sure which package is sufficient enough for me to make all my requests without it being throttled.

Comment: Don't know if I can help you in that case, but just to make sure: Are you running the client or the server (or both) and which one throttles?

Comment: I'm running the client that grabs the HTML from a server (website) using the Requests library. I know the server isn't denying my request because I am able to run it fine with about 30 requests/sec on a personal machine but with AWS after a short while I get a Request Error of 444. So I believe the client (when hosted on AWS) is being throttled or that's what it seems like to me.